# rollup in MDX: calculated member to overrite a real measure

Tags: mdx

[measures].[Alert Count] is a real measure (based on a column in the fact table).

```
CREATE  MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[test6] as [measures].[Alert Count];  
([Store].[Store].[Store].members*[Calendar].[Date].[Date].members ,[measures].[test6]) = 2;
```

Since the last scope assignment overwrite the measure of test6 to 2, so I expect the following to return 4 for every cell of test because we sliced with 2 dates, and each day has a test6 as 2, then rollup to get 2+2=4.  But the actual result is not:  test6 is always equal to  [alert count].

```
select {[Measures].[test6],[measures].[Alert Count]} on 0,    
[STORE].[STORE].[STORE].members on 1    
from [test]    
where {[CALENDAR].[Date].&[2011-05-21T00:00:00],[CALENDAR].[Date].&[2011-06-12T00:00:00]}
```

The following works expected: test6 is always 2.

```
select  {[Measures].[test6],[measures].[Alert Count]} on 0,
[STORE].[STORE].[STORE].members on 1
from [test]
where {[CALENDAR].[Date].&[2011-05-21T00:00:00]}
```

Comment: what OLAP server are you using? strange the syntax after the ;

Answer (score 0):

What if you add a new member?

```
With Member [Measures].[test7] As Sum({[CALENDAR].[Date].&[2011-05-21T00:00:00],[CALENDAR].[Date].&[2011-06-12T00:00:00]}, [Measures].[test6])
select {[Measures].[test6], [Measures].[test7],[measures].[Alert Count]} on 0,    
[STORE].[STORE].[STORE].members on 1    
from [test]    
where {[CALENDAR].[Date].&[2011-05-21T00:00:00],[CALENDAR].[Date].&[2011-06-12T00:00:00]}
```

is it useful?